# Gimp 2.10.14: How to make the panels bigger on 4K monitor?

Tags: gimp

I am using a 4K monitor with 200% system DPI. (200% is a little big for me and I would like to use 150%, but some applications did not scale well under 150%, so I had to choose 200% DPI.) Now, I am using the latest version of Gimp, and it does not seem to scale properly. For the tool icons, I chose "Huge" in the "Custom icon size", but I could not find any options to make other panels bigger.

See the relative size below. The tool buttons next to "Move" are too small to see.
[image]

I used 400% magnification, and now you see the buttons...

[image]

I found an answer that suggests adding `GimpToolPalette::tool-icon-size   = large-toolbar` to "gtkrc", but that had no effect. Is there any way to properly size the panels?

Comment: You need to install a suitable "theme" (actually possibly two, one for the icons and one for the general looks).

Answer (score 0):

**Here's how I solved the 4k display issue with GIMP 2.10.32:**

Find GIMP in start menu Right click on it, select "more" then select "open file location"

Right click on GIMP and select "Properties"

Select "Compatibility" tab

Select "Change high DPI settings"

Tick the box: "Override high DPI scaling behaviour'

Choose: "Scaling performed by": System

Click "OK"

Now open GIMP and Icons/Toolboxes/etc should look correct size.

It works for me. I hope it does for you as well.